# Android-App in Kotlin: Updating imageView only updates last option

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to "animate" a dice rolling in the Dice-Roller App from the Kotlin Learning path from Google. I try to set an ImageView with an drawable, "sleep" a little bit and update it again, this a few times till it stops at the random generated number.

When i use (Option 1):

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollButton.isClickable = false
            rollDice()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            rollDice()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            rollDice()
            rollButton.isClickable = true
        }
```

it just sleeps and dont updates 3 times. The image just updates once after 2 seconds.

Same when i try to handle it inside the `rollDice()` with (Option 2):

```
        // Play Roll - Animation
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
        Thread.sleep(1000)

        // Update the ImageView with the correct drawable resource ID
        diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)
```

App: ( https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-dice-roller-images?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-dice-roller-images#6 )

Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /**
     * This method is called when the Activity is created.
     */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Find the Button in the layout
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        // Set a click listener on the button to roll the dice when the user taps the button
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            // HERE WOULD BE OPTION 1  -------------------!!!!!!
            rollButton.isClickable = false
            rollDice()
            rollButton.isClickable = true
        }

        // Do a dice roll when the app starts
        rollDice()
    }

    /**
     * Roll the dice and update the screen with the result.
     */
    private fun rollDice() {
        // Create new Dice object with 6 sides and roll it
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()

        // Find the ImageView in the layout
        val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        // Determine which drawable resource ID to use based on the dice roll
        val drawableResource = when (diceRoll) {
            1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
            2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
            3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
            4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
            5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
            else -> R.drawable.dice_6
        }

        // Play Roll - Animation
        // HERE IS OPTION 2 -------------------!!!!!!
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
        Thread.sleep(1000)

        // Update the ImageView with the correct drawable resource ID
        diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)

        // Update the content description
        diceImage.contentDescription = diceRoll.toString()
    }
}

/**
 * Dice with a fixed number of sides.
 */
class Dice(private val numSides: Int) {

    /**
     * Do a random dice roll and return the result.
     */
    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

I tried now for 3 days to find an answer, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are setting image resource and immediately after you are putting the main thread responsible of redrawing your views and updating the imageview to sleep for a second and doing the same thing after that. This is not advisable but still if you want to do the animation like that try to use [Coroutine](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#0) instead.

But if you still would like to use threads you can use this instead
write this inside click listener

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                rollDiceInMain();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                rollDiceInMain();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                rollDiceInMain();
                runOnUiThread {
                    rollButton.isClickable = true
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

And have another method rollDiceOnMain like this

```
private void rollDiceInMain() {
    runOnUiThread {
        rollDice()
    }
}
```